# kali live usb not persistant

Tags: linux, kali-linux, liveusb

I've been searching a lot but can't find the answer to my problem. I made a kali linux live boot flash drive. I am using an UEFI system so I made the drive boot-able using this tutorial

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/66948-uefi-kali-linux-live-usb-on-surface-pro

That was succesful in making the drive boot-able. When I boot the drive there are a couple of options for boot. One of them is a persistant mode. However, this mode doesn't work as persistant. None of the changes are saved. So I used this tutorial to try and add persistence.

http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence

After I completed the tutorial I did not see any other boot options. My understanding is that this should add another mode to boot into. I also tried the original persistence mode and it still does not work. So my question is this... does anyone know how to add the new persistence to the boot menu? Or perhaps why my persistence isn't working?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with the new files from the first tutorial. The grub.cfg file lists out the boot options but I'm not sure how to alter it to point at the persistence partition I made

Answer (score 1):

Well after days of trying I finally got to the bottom of it. There is a line under the boot - persistent entry in the grub.cfg that needs to be changed.

`linuxefi /live/vmlinuz boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence`

needs to be changed to

```
linuxefi /live/vmlinuz boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali persistence persistence-encryption=luks
```

Now I'm not sure why the non-encryted encryption won't work since the only difference is the `persistence-encryption=luks` But encrypted persistence is working like a charm

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I don't even know where I could find this! Very helpful! I love you!